# Как увидеть захваченную переменую?

Tags: c#

Читая Герберта Шилдта, дошел до раздела "Применение внешних переменных в анонимных методах" где в частности сказано:

> Захваченная переменная существует до тех пор, пока захвативший ее делегат не будет собран в "мусор".

А как мне в этом можно убедится? В том, что переменная действительно существует после выхода из кодового блока. Отладчик в Visual Studio говорит:

> error CS0103: The name 'variable' does not exist in the current context.

Вот пример кода:

```
class Program
{
    delegate void MyDelegate();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test();
    }

    static void Test()
    {
        int i;
        MyDelegate myDelegate = delegate { i = 10; Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()); };
        myDelegate();
    }
}
```

Тут переменная `i` будет жить до сборки мусора.

Comment: существование и видимость - разные вещи. Код покажите.

Comment: Вам по сути нужно знать уничтожил ли GC вашу переменную. Собственно у него это и уточните.

Comment: @Alexey - Товарищ пытается посмотреть дебаггером значение переменной, находясь в том месте кода, где ее не видно.

Comment: Эээ... А _зачем_ вам нужно убедиться? Ваш делегат может её использовать — вам этого не достаточно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переменная и область видимости - это понятия уровня языка, а не уровня рантайма.

После IL-компиляции переменная превращается в одну из двух вещей:
- значение в стеке
- поле класса-замыкания

После JIT-компиляции и значения в стеке, и значения полей замыкания могут местами кешироваться еще и в регистрах процессора.

То, что вы хотите проверить - это существование класса-замыкания в куче после того, управление покинуло область видимости локальной переменной. Можно проверить студией, или любым другим отладчиком, позволяющим смотреть содержимое кучи:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Debugger.Break();

    {
        string var1 = "somevalue";
        Action a = () => { var1 = "newvalue"; };
    }

    Debugger.Break();
}
```

после остановки на первом брейке открыть Debug -> Show Diagnostic Tools, и нажать Memory Usage / Take Snapshot.

продолжить выполнение, на втором брейке нажать Take Snapshot еще раз. И сравнить снапшоты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно что и объект замыкания и локальная переменная еще живы, кроме того, в path to root для обоих показывается что они являются локальными переменными метода.

Картина чуть поменяется при запуске в Release не под отладчиком. Следующий код покажет нулевой дифф - оптимизатор просто выбросит все неиспользуемое:

```
Debugger.Launch();

{
    string var1 = "somevalue";
    Action a = () => { var1 = "newvalue"; };
}

Debugger.Break();
```

А вот если вы продлите время жизни Action, то сможете увидеть что объект-замыкание жив, хотя переменная уже недоступна:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action a;

    Debugger.Launch();

    {
        string var1 = "somevalue";
        a = () => { var1 = "newvalue"; };
    }

    Debugger.Break();

    a();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Великолепный ответ! То, что было нужно! Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 4):

*"Захваченная переменная существует до тех пор, пока захвативший ее делегат не будет собран в "мусор""* всего лишь означает, что, как и в абсолютно всех других случаях, если объект может быть хоть каким-то образом достигнут (в данном случае через замыкание), то он не будет собран сборщиком мусора. Это работает абсолютно всегда, и замыкания (которые представляют собой классы, где поля — все захваченные переменные) — не исключение.

Проверить это не так просто, потому что, если ссылка на экземпляр замыкания — это единственный "маршрут" к объекту, то извлечь его можно только с помощью отражений. Но не будем шаманствовать, вместо этого проверим внешне наблюдаемое поведение на деле.

Для начала заведём класс, который будет сообщать нам, что сборка мусора и последующая финализация до него добрались:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

class Named
{
    string _name;

    public Named (string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        WriteLine($"{_name} created");
    }

    ~Named ()
    {
        WriteLine($"{_name} finalized");
    }
}
```

А дальше проверяем:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main () => new Program().Run();

    Func<string> _act;

    void Run ()
    {
        LocalVariable();
        CollectGarbage();

        LocalVariableUsedByAnonymousMethod();
        CollectGarbage();

        CallAnonymousDelegateAndForgetIt();
        CollectGarbage();

        WriteLine("Done!");
    }

    void LocalVariable ()
    {
        WriteLine("Local variable:");
        var foo = new Named("Foo");
    }

    void LocalVariableUsedByAnonymousMethod ()
    {
        WriteLine("Local variable used by anonymous method:");
        var bar = new Named("Bar");
        _act = () => bar.ToString();
    }

    void CallAnonymousDelegateAndForgetIt ()
    {
        WriteLine($"Result of ToString: {_act()}");
        _act = null;
    }

    void CollectGarbage ()
    {
        WriteLine("Collecting garbage.");
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        WriteLine("Collected garbage.");
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Local variable:
Foo created
Collecting garbage.
Foo finalized
Collected garbage.

Local variable used by anonymous method:
Bar created
Collecting garbage.
Collected garbage.
Result of ToString: Named
Collecting garbage.
Bar finalized
Collected garbage.

Done!
```

Как можно видеть, объект "Foo" был собран после выхода из метода, в котором был создан, а объект "Bar" просуществовал до момента, когда на него пропали все ссылки, в том числе из замыкания.

Answer (score 1):

Самая надежная проверка - декомпилятор. Например, [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy).

Любое замыкание преобразуется компилятором во внутренний класс, а захваченные переменные становятся полями этого класса. В декомпиляторе этот класс можно увидеть, со всеми своими полями.

PS при использовании ILSpy для того, чтобы увидеть сгенерированные классы-замыкания, надо выключить декомпиляцию замыканий в настройках. В противном случае декомпилятор их разпознает и скроет.

Comment: И как декомпилятор поможет в рантайме узнать жива ли ещё переменная?